# Binding TokenInput and razor code to the same model?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

In an HTML form how do you bind jquery controls (e.g. tokeninput) the same way you bind the ordinary primitive types to the model?  I am struggling to find ways to do this and I know you can use custom templates etc, but there is nothing for jquery plugins.

Specifically I am using tokenInput see here (http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/).
Here is the jQuery code that I apply against a standard HTML text input.  For every keypress it goes to the controller to return a list of authors.  You can also pre-populate with authors, and I use the data tags in HTML5 to prepopulate the control.

```
 $("#AUTHORs").tokenInput('/author/getauthors/', {
        hintText: "Enter surname",
        searchingText: "Searching...",
        preventDuplicates: true,
        allowCustomEntry: true,
        highlightDuplicates: false,
        tokenDelimiter: "*",
        resultsLimit: 10,
        theme: "facebook",
        prePopulate: $('#AUTHORs').data('AUTHORs')
    });
```

I have posted a bit of code from my view just to show you exactly what I am trying to bind to the model.

```
@model myModels.BOOK

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Basic</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TITLE)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field" >
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TITLE)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TITLE)
        </div>
    <div class="authors">
            <div class="editor-field">
                <input type="text" id="authors" name="authors" data-val="true"  data-val-required="You must enter at least one author" data-authors="@Json.Encode(Model.AUTHORs.Select(a => new { id = a.AUTHOR_ID, name = a.FULL_NAME }))"/>
                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="authors" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

and here is the code that I use when trying to update the model (after pressing "Save") on the form:

```
  [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(BOOK book)
        {
             if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(book).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = book.REF_ID });
            }
            ViewBag.REF_ID = new SelectList(db.REFERENCEs, "REF_ID", "REF_ID", book.REF_ID);
            return View(book);
        }
```

---

When you look at the code in the HTML it has formatted the authors from the tokeninput element it looks like so, and it seems that this format it has a real problem with I think:

```
<input type="text" id="AUTHORs" name="AUTHORs" data-val="true" data-val-required="You must enter at least one author" data-authors="

[{&quot;id&quot;:156787,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Faure,M.&quot;},

{&quot;id&quot;:177433,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Wang,D.Z.&quot;},

{&quot;id&quot;:177434,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Shu,L.Sh&quot;},

{&quot;id&quot;:177435,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Sheng,W.Z.&quot;}]"

style="display: none; ">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you are using the [tokeninput plugin](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/). Let's have a step-by-step example about how this could be implemented with ASP.NET MVC:

Model:

```
public class Book
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Author> Authors { get; set; }
}

public class Author
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // fake a database. Obviously that in your actual application
    // this information will be coming from a database or something
    public readonly static Dictionary<int, string> Authors = new Dictionary<int, string>
    {
        { 1, "foo" },
        { 2, "bar" },
        { 3, "baz" },
        { 4, "bazinga" },
    };

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // preinitialize the model with some values => obviously in your
        // real application those will be coming from a database or something
        var model = new Book
        {
            Title = "some title",
            Authors = new[] 
            {
                new Author { Id = 2, Name = "bar" }
            }
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Book book)
    {
        return Content(string.Format("thanks for selecting authors: {0}", string.Join(" ", book.Authors.Select(x => x.Name))));
    }

    public ActionResult GetAuthors(string q)
    {
        var authors = Authors.Select(x => new
        {
            id = x.Key,
            name = x.Value
        });
        return Json(authors, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model Book
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Title)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Title)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(
            x => x.Authors, 
            new { 
                id = "authors", 
                data_url = Url.Action("GetAuthors", "Home"), 
                data_authors = Json.Encode(
                    Model.Authors.Select(
                        x => new { id = x.Id, name = x.Name }
                    )
                ) 
            }
        )
    </div>
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}

<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery.tokeninput.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var authors = $('#authors');
    authors.tokenInput(authors.data('url'), {
        hintText: 'Enter surname',
        searchingText: 'Searching...',
        preventDuplicates: true,
        allowCustomEntry: true,
        highlightDuplicates: false,
        tokenDelimiter: '*',
        resultsLimit: 10,
        theme: 'facebook',
        prePopulate: authors.data('authors')
    });
</script>
```

and the last step is to write a custom model binder which will retrieve the authors form the ids:

```
public class AuthorModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var values = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        if (values != null)
        {
            // We have specified asterisk (*) as a token delimiter. So
            // the ids will be separated by *. For example "2*3*5"
            var ids = values.AttemptedValue.Split('*').Select(int.Parse);

            // Now that we have the selected ids we could fetch the corresponding
            // authors from our datasource
            var authors = HomeController.Authors.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Key)).Select(x => new Author
            {
                Id = x.Key,
                Name = x.Value
            }).ToList();
            return authors;
        }
        return Enumerable.Empty<Author>();
    }
}
```

that will be registered in Application_Start:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(IEnumerable<Author>), new AuthorModelBinder());
```

Comment: It seems I can't apply indexing to the collection AUTHOR, any ideas?

Comment: You should declare it as either `IList<T>` or `T[]` in your view model so that you can apply indexing.

Comment: I don't understand how is this input field generated and why can't you use standard binding techniques. Did you read the 2 posts I have linked to?

Comment: Sorry about this, I forgot to include details about tokenInput, it basically works with a text input box - I will update my question.

Comment: What is the user supposed to enter inside this input box? Only the values of input elements will be sent to the server. HTML5 `data-*` elements will not.

Comment: OK, now that you have more clearly specified that you are trying to use the jQuery.tokenInput plugin I have updated my answer to illustrate a step-by-step guide about how you could implement it.

Comment: Hey Darin that's very kind of you - should learn loads from this (very excited!!) :)

Comment: Also just to say that I used the "*" delimiter because a "," is a legitimate character I want to use for an authors name, and that could mess formatting up, so I thought an "*" is unlikely to be part of anyone's name - hence a good delimiter character.

Comment: The Author's name is never sent to the server by the jQuery.tokenInput plugin. Only the ids. So the request will look like this: `2*3*5`. It's up to you to select the corresponding model values in the custom model binder as I have illustrated in my answer.

Comment: The custom model binder doesn't seem to be invoked during debugging? is there anything missing?, I have added the line in the correct place in the Global.asax file.

Comment: If you have added the following line in your `Application_Start`: `ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(IEnumerable<Author>), new AuthorModelBinder());` and your Index POST action is taking the view model exactly as shown in my answer: `[HttpPost] public ActionResult Index(Book book) { ... }` then the custom model binder will be invoked. I guess you didn't follow my answer step by step. You must have missed something. Please create a new ASP.NET MVC application and try implementing what I have shown here - it should work. Once you have a working version you could start adapting it to your needs.

Comment: Yep - tried your code in a new project - it definitely works! Oh well, just need to find the diffs.

Comment: Right! In the Application_Start, I had to put the Author array as  type, IColletion e.g. ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(ICollection<AUTHOR>), new AuthorModelBinder()), instead of IEnumerable, this is due to me not noticing the differences between your code and the auto generated T4 model code and more importantly how custom Model Binders are triggered from the incoming POST. The part of the model to be custom model bound must match the exact signiture decalared in Application_Start of the Global.asax.  Phew! (and thanks again Darin for all your help).

Comment: @Vidar, ah, good spot on this. I am glad that you have manged to get this solution working.

Comment: Sorry to extend this problem further (if a new question is needed I'll be happy to create one).  However, all is working (kind of) and the new authors get sent back to EDIT/POST - but when you try to update the model with say, 2 extra authors - they never stick or get properly bound to the model, I just get the same amount of authors as before (even though on intellisense I can see the new authors there!), they just don't get saved back into the database - why would this happen?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

```
$("form").on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);

    $.ajax({
       url: form.attr('action'),
       type: form.attr('method'),
       data: form.serialize(),
       success: function(r) { }
    });
});
```

Comment: I have to be honest - I don't understand why using this would help me bind to my model?  Can you provide some background thinking?  :)

Comment: @vidar This code will collect all form data and send them to the server, where binder will fill your model.

Comment: I have added more code to show what format the tokeninput element is spitting out in form of data - the model binder will not bind to this it seems.  I have also been thinking, to I need to have a proper  @Html.EditorFor - Authors? so that it binds?, at the moment I have just put down some explicit HTML.

Comment: @Vidar yes, this code will just serialize data as normal POST request, with html5 attributes it wont work.

Comment: ok - so there must be some other way to properly bind this control into the model...any ideas? :)

Comment: @Vidar just add hidden fields.

Comment: what about using a custom model binder to work with tokeninput?

Comment: @Vidar Open `fiddler` and view post data, this field wont send.

Comment: you can find the values in the Form.Request[foo], but this is not a great way - I'm not sure I understand your last comment.

Answer (score 0):

`data-authors="@Json.Encode(Model.AUTHORs.Select(a => new { id = a.AUTHOR_ID, name = a.FULL_NAME }))`"

I think this should be :

```
data-authors="@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.AUTHORs.Select(a => new { id = a.AUTHOR_ID, name = a.FULL_NAME })))"
```

Answer (score 0):

I made small test - and seems that kind of attribute text is not an error and correclty recognized by browser as JSON object

Try to add expression  `$("#authorlist").data("authors")` to watch in your browser (press F12) or execute it in console - for me it returns valid javascript object.

Comment: Yes - I get back the values fine (at least the id's) - but they are not bound back into the model in the EDIT part of the controller.  So when you look at the intellisense for the model - it shows AUTHORS as having 0 even though the id's are there in the form e.g. var test = Request.Form["Authors"]

Comment: This is how HTML work: to have it bound back in controller you need to have: input|select|textarea, you need `name` for it and you need value for that inputs. In this case it will appear in POST request. Otherwise you should use AJAX or write custom code to have it back on server.